# Oracle APEX interactive Grid displays too many duplicates

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have 3 tables: Employees, Locations, and EmpLocation

- Employees stores employee data with Employee_ID as primary key,
- Locations stores location data with Location_ID.
- EmpLocation stores Employee_ID and Location_ID. Each Employee can have multiple locations.

I have created an Interactive Grid that is based on the data from EmpLocation table:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, LOCATION_ID
FROM EmpLocation
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID, LOCATION_ID
```

Then each of the columns I set as a select list and use SQL query as a source:

```
SELECT Employee_FName, Employee_ID FROM Employees
```

and

```
SELECT LocationName, Location_ID FROM Locations
```

Everything looks fine but when I run query

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, LOCATION_ID
FROM EmpLocation
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID, LOCATION_ID
```

in TOAD, I get about 100 records; but in the grid I get many duplicates. Cannot figure out what is going on...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you allow duplicates in the EmpLocation table at the first place? What would be the point in keeping

```
Littlefoot        Croatia        --> this ...
Coding Duchess    Somewhere
Littlefoot        Croatia        --> ... and this are duplicates
```

Create unique index

```
create unique index ui_emploc on emplocation (employee_id, location_id);
```

Doing so, you'd avoid `group by` clause you currently use. Though, why do you use it? What's wrong with *usual* way of getting distinct values, i.e.

```
select distinct employee_id, location_id
from emplocation;
```

As of Apex & its Interactive Grid joys of all kinds (although it looks pretty, I still prefer tabular form over it): what happens if you create a classic report (instead of an interactive grid) - do you still see duplicates?

Comment: but the things is there are no duplicates in the EmpLocation table. There could be more than one location per each employee but no duplicates. (Ex: Littlefoot - Croatia, Littlefoot - France)

Comment: I am using IG because I will be doing inserts and updates and IG has all that functionality and more

Comment: I think I figured it out - each column I made a select list and I must have set it up the wrong way and it messed up the grid. Because if I remove select list and make each column a text box, I get about a 100 of records, just like I am supposed to

Comment: OK, I'm glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with duplicate rows shown in IG, although the result of the report query tested in Toad does not include duplicates. The reason I found:
If using Select List in the IG and that Select List have duplicates than the IG show this buggy behaivor.